# Does the NullPointerException really depend on the location of the class?

Tags: java, maven, javassist

I have two classes in a Maven project, which contain the same code (except for their name). The code shall later create a new class with Javassist based on a csv-file.

The first one `CsvParser` is placed in the `src/main/java/csvParser` package. The second one `TestCsvParser` is placed in the `src/test/java/csvParser` package. In both packages the same file `assistant.csv` is placed.

When I run the one from the `main` directory (`CsvParser`) I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` but when I run `TestCsvParser`, placed in the `test`directory the same code works fine.

Why is it like that? (Or do I just not see something? ;) )

`CsvParser`:

```
package csvParser;    

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;    

public class CsvParser {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        createClass("/assistant.csv");
    }    

    /**
     * Create a class from a csv-file.
     */
    private static void createClass(String input) throws IOException {
        try(BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                CsvParser.class.getResourceAsStream(input))))
        {
            // Create class based on csv-file.
        }
    }
}
```

`TestCsvParser`:

```
package csvParser;    

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;    

public class TestCsvParser {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        createClass("/assistant.csv");
    }    

    /**
     * Create a class from a csv-file.
     */
    private static void createClass(String input) throws IOException {
        try(BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                TestCsvParser.class.getResourceAsStream(input))))
        {
            // Create class based on csv-file.
        }
    }
}
```

The exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at csvParser.CsvParser.createClass(CsvParser.java:19)
    at csvParser.CsvParser.main(CsvParser.java:11)
```

I believe this question is not a duplicate of a question like `What is a NullPointerException` because:
The `NullPointerException` occurs based on the location of the class and the resource referred to. So it's more about directory structures and Mavens `target`directory.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: show us the exception also please

Comment: check **assistant.csv** is present in your resource folder of maven project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the error. I added the `assistant.csv` beside the two classes (`CsvParser` and `TestCsvParser`). But in both cases this file is not added to the target directory.

The reason why it was working in `TestCsvParser` is an additional `assistant.csv` in the `../test/resource/` directory. In fact the two conditions which I described missed this fact and therefore you could not reconstruct my error fully. I'm sorry for that.

To have a working example the resource files both for `main` and `test` have to placed within the `resource` folder instead of beside the class.

Thanks for your help, especially [Kalaiselvan A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3454928/kalaiselvan-a).

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on location of "/assistant.csv" file and if it's not found, you will get NPE. The path will be dependent on your class location since you are calling `CsvParser.class.getResourceAsStream..`

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand you, but the file is placed in both directories. Both times just beside the class.

Comment: then where is NPE? I guess it is in finding the input resource... if not, at what line you see NPE?

Comment: @SoS To validate what I am saying try printing this. `CsvParser.class.getResource("/assistant.csv")` and you will know where it is null.

Comment: `CsvParser.class.getResource("/assistant.csv")` returns `null`. `TestCsvParser.class.getResource("/assistant.csv")` returns `file:/C:/Users/User/IdeaProjects/ComponentClassification/target/test-classes/assistant.csv`. So you are right, but that does not explain why it is like it is ;).

Comment: it is very much like that, because your assitant.csv may not be getting copied to target/classes when you run the non test class.

Comment: @SoS If you see, the file is looked under test-classes for test and for main, it will be looked under `/target/classes/` or whatever is the class folder for main file.